# Caliburn View Model First only in part of project

Tags: caliburn.micro

Is it possible to have the `Caliburn.Micro` `ViewModel` first feature without attaching the bootstrapper to `App.xaml` and without calling `DisplayRootViewFor<MainWindowViewModel>()` in the `OnStartup()` method?

Best regards

Comment: You could load your window with window manager, but why do you want to do that?

Comment: We cannot modify the main window and application startup, but we would like to use view model first approach in our sub component.

Comment: If you cannot modify `Startup` inside `App.xaml` then your application will always load from the default start file. You could try to do this:`IoC.Get<IWindowManager>().ShowWindow(IoC.GetInstance(typeof(YourViewModel), null), null, null);`(this is what `DisplayRootViewFor` does internally), but I don't think it will work, because you have `Startup` property inside `App.xaml` and you may end up with 2 windows showing up...